# What is the optimal IDE/text editor print margin when programming?

Tags: coding-style

Considering today's monitors and programming fonts that look quite good at small point sizes, what is the optimal print margin to set in your IDE/text editor?

I have been using the age-old 80 characters for most of my career but Code Complete has made me consider a 90 character margin.

Is 100 going too far or is it really up to the developer/team involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you have a very large screen, reading long lines is more difficult than reading short lines.

Besides, the extra space can be used to show other informations. I work in a team that uses very long lines (120 characters) which is fine when the text editor is in full-screen mode, but the text is often truncated when other panels are open.

Comment: We have settled on 100 characters. It's long enough that most statements don't have to be continued on the next line, and short enough to be readable both in our editors and when diffing.